# Trying to set header() in php so the page can show UTF-8 chars

Tags: php, forms, email, character-encoding

I have this php script laying in it's own file to work together with a contact form. The php looks like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From:test@127.0.0.1'; 
    $to = 'example@stackoverflow.com'; 
    $subject = 'Ang. Website';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {              
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Ditt meddelande har skickats! Klicka på bakåt för att komma tillbaka till Microscopium.</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Någonting gick fel, var vänlig försök igen!</p>';
    }
    } 
?>
```

But still the error message will look like this:

> NÃ¥gonting gick fel, var vÃ¤nlig gÃ¥ tillbaka och fÃ¶rsÃ¶k igen.

HTML head looks like this if it matters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/effects.js"></script>
    <script src="mail.php"></script>
    <title>Microscopium</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the php file is stored as UTF-8.

Comment: Hmm, i did "Save with encoding --> UTF-8" in sublime, but I'm still getting invalid chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your php's internal encoding with [mb_internal_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)

```
<?php
/* Set internal character encoding to UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

/* Display current internal character encoding */
echo mb_internal_encoding();
?>
```

Make sure it's on UTF-8.

And as jgroenen said: be sure your php files are stored as UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, something else seems to be wrong here. I added your code to the php and commented out the if/else but the error message is still showing up.

Comment: Does mb_internal_encoding() say 'UTF-8'? Another thing you can try is to echo utf8_encode('your string'); Let me know your results.

Comment: I'm stupid, it was working all along. I was editing the local file but tesing the one on localhost. It all works now!